# Оцените код верстки блока по сетке

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, инспекция-кода

Написал вот такой страшненький код:

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
}

.q {
  padding: 0;
}

.y {
  height: 100%;
}

.c {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6 a">
        <div class=""><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/540x540" alt=""></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 a">
        <div class="container y q">
          <div class="row y">
            <div class="col-12 "><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/540x255" alt=""></div>

            <div class="col-6 c"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/255x255" alt=""></div>
            <div class="col-6 c"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/255x255" alt=""></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</html>
```

Какие претензии есть к коду? Если возможно покажите как бы вы реализовали этот блок на бутстрап сетке. Как сделать так чтобы с уменьшением экрана отступы на не сильно не выпирали? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: У классов должны быть осмысленные имена, на теги глобально не следует накидывать, на строчные блочные свойства не следует применять

Comment: @kizoso а как вам вообще структура сетки? Можно ли было обойтись без вложенного контейнера?

Comment: точно, контейнера внутри колонки быть не может, почитайте документацию

Comment: @midia судя по тем стилям, которые вы прописали для класса "с", знакомы с флекс-боксами. Зачем Вы тогда вообще используете бутстрап? Вам не кажется, что на нативных флекс-боксах все то же самое реализовать проще? Ну это так, флуд...

Answer (score 0):

Определил для классов col-6 col-12 padding в процентах

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
}

.q {
  padding: 0;
}
.col-6, .col-12 { padding: 0 2% !important; }
.y {
  height: 100%;
}

.c {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6 a">
        <div class=""><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/540x540" alt=""></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 a">
        <div class="container y q">
          <div class="row y">
            <div class="col-12 "><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/540x255" alt=""></div>

            <div class="col-6 c"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/255x255" alt=""></div>
            <div class="col-6 c"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/255x255" alt=""></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</html>
```